# How to use block device attached to host, as block device within the pod

Tags: kubernetes

Question: How can I use raw devices attached to the host within the pod as block device.

I tried using "hostPath" with type "BlockDevice"

```
volumes:
- my-data:
  hostPath:
    path: /dev/nvme1n2
    type: BlockDevice
```

```
containers:
.....
  volumeDevices:
  - name: my-data
    devicePath: /dev/sda
```

This configuration gives me the below error.

```
Invalid value: "my-data": can only use volume source type of PersistentVolumeClaim for block mode
```

Can I achieve this using `PersistentVolume` and `PersistentVolumeClaim` ? Can someone help me with an example config. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Support for Block devices in K8s](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#raw-block-volume-support) allows user and admins to use PVs & PVCs for raw block devices to be mounted in Pods. Excerpts below show a small use-case.

- Create a PV which refers the Raw device on host say `/dev/xvdf`.

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: local-raw-pv
spec:
  volumeMode: Block
  capacity:
    storage: 100Gi
  local:
    path: /dev/xvdf
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
```

- Create a PVC claiming the block device for applications

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: block-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeMode: Block
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

- Create pod with the above claim which will mount the host device `/dev/xvdf` inside pod at path `/dev/xvda`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod-with-block-volume
spec:
  containers:
    - name: some-container
      image: ubuntu
      command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
      args: [ "tail -f /dev/null" ]
      volumeDevices:
        - name: data
          devicePath: /dev/xvda
  volumes:
    - name: data
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: block-pvc
```

Comment: How do I give permissions to the pod to run mount the block device? Is it possible? I've formatted with ext4 within the pod and then mount gives me permission denied, even with SYS_ADMIN capability added to the container